# Computing condition number of a polynomial root finding probelm

Tags: computational-complexity

Trefethen & Bau ("numerical linear algebra"; 1997) compute the condition number of polynomial root finding for $f(x) = (x-1)^2$ to be $k=\infty$ because the Jacobian does not exist. I want to know and understand the derivation of that result, because the book only explains it in words with an example perturbation of $x^2-2+0.9999 = (x-0.99)(x-1.01)$. Thank you.

Comment: Condition number has to do with the size of the change in output for a small change in input, right? So if you change the input to $(x-1)^2-\epsilon^2$, you change the output (that is, the root of the polynomial) by $\epsilon$, and the ratio of change of output to change of input is $\epsilon/\epsilon^2$, which is $1/\epsilon$, which goes to infinity as $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry for your very intuitive clarification. That makes sense.